# .htaccess rewrite URL for my website

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

maybe you can help me to rewrite my URL (i never worked with a .htacces-file).

Example:
I have a URL like this: http://localhost/index.php?s=example

How i can chance this URL like this: http://localhost/example ?

Maybe you can help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in `root/.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?s=$1 [NC,L]
```

This script will allow you to access `/index.php?s=foobar` using the clean url `/foobar`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what do you mean with root/.htaccess ? and how i can get the $_GET['index'] with this solution?

Comment: @iseven **Root/.htaccess** is your htaccess file located in the root/public_html folder. You can access/get dyanamic value of the uri **/foobar** using **$_GET["s"]** in your php page

Comment: Hello, do this work with xampp on my local machine? It actually dont work for me.. Are there any other settings? And i must do nothing else to use $_GET['s'] in my php page?

Comment: Hi,


This works fine on my server. As far as I think you actually don't know how url-rewriting works, please take a look at the basic 

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html