# Url rewriting in php with multiple query string variables using .htacces

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

I have dynamic pages in php like:

```
http://www.example.com/page.php?tokenid=1&tokenname=About Us
```

I want to remove this part:

```
.php?tokenid=1&tokenname=About Us
```

page extension with query string and show the url as:

```
http://www.example.com/About Us
```

**Update:**

What I've tried so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    #RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]*)?/(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,E=PATH_INFO:/$2,L]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]*)?/(.*)$ $1.php/$2 [QSA,E=PATH_INFO:/$2,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]

    # Fix PHP Authentication with FastCGI mode
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} !''
    RewriteRule .*php - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @EhsanT yes i have tried lot of things from google but acutaully could not find the suitable solution.

Comment: So if you have tried anything, when you are posting your question, please include your code(whatever you have tried)

Comment: @EhsanT i have tried this code:

Comment: @EhsanT i have tried this code:
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 #RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]*)?/(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,E=PATH_INFO:/$2,L]
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]*)?/(.*)$ $1.php/$2 [QSA,E=PATH_INFO:/$2,L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [QSA,L]


 # Fix PHP Authentication with FastCGI mode
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} !''
 RewriteRule .*php - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
</IfModule>

Comment: You can get some ideas from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41325447/1908331). But your question was somehow misleading and that was the reason the answer @sepehr provided did not solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your .htaccess file:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Skip actual files/directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# If the host matches example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
# And the request URI starts with page.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/page\.php
# And the querystring matches tokenid=DIGIT&tokenname=TOKEN_NAME
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tokenid=\d&tokenname=(.*)
# Then rewrite the URI to TOKEN_NAME
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1? [L,R]
```

You might want to [try it online](http://htaccess.mwl.be/), if you wish.

[image]

Comment: i have tried your suggestion, but i am getting error 404 page, i am not able to retrive the page content.

Comment: As far as the apache's rewrite module is concerned, you're correctly redirecting to `/About Us` page. You need to make sure that the URI actually exists. Adding a rewrite rule does not magically make that page available.

Comment: yes but i am fetching the page from database based on tokenid and tokenname and i am rewriting the url so that the user does not see the extra query string .